# How to calculate Likelihood of a value given a distribution?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, log-likelihood

I'm trying to get a score that tells me the probability of a value belongs to distribution or not. Score that maybe i wrongly called likelihood.
For example:

```
A = [4,5,5,6,4,16,15,14,15,16]
b = 5
```

In this case my score should be low and i want a low score even if b = 15 otherwise I would an high score if b = 10 or worse if b = 100.

I tried to use Kernel Density to fit a mixture of gaussians on my data A and then I tried to get a score for b. 
But it doesn't seem what I really want.

```
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian').fit(A)
score = kde.score(b)
```

Do you have any suggestion to model the problem in a better way ?

EDIT:
A is a list of value generates from neural network and b is the real value that I'm trying to predict.
KernelDensity doesn't seem good because when A and b are for example:

```
A = [40,50,50,60,40,160,150,140,150,160]
b = 50
```

the score is higher than the first case while it should be the same.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what did you get with this and why it does not fit your expectation ?

Comment: A is the whole probability distribution ? or is it a sample ?
Are you talking about a continuous or a discrete distribution ?
You should provide more explanation. This question sounds like a questions in Statistics rather than programming

Comment: I edited the question, A it's a list of samples from the distrubition that i'm trying to rebuild.